# -bash: lstat: command not found

Tags: command-line, osx, stat, darwin

I'm using a Macbook Pro running El Capitan v 10.11.6.  I am learning about symlinks, and in the `man ln` page, I found the following:

> A stat(2) on a symbolic link will return the linked-to file; an lstat(2) must be done to obtain information about the link.

As a test, I created a symlink to a file (in another filesystem, if it matters), as follows:

`ln -s /Volumes/foobardir/foobarfile foobarlink`

Then I ran `lstat foobarlink` to get information on the symlink file itself, but I got the following output:

`-bash: lstat: command not found`

The command `which lstat` returns nothing, which confirms that there is no executable with this name in my filepath.

I am able to execute `stat foobarlink`, but I am not sure if the returned stats are for the linked file or the symlink itself.  I do see today's date in timestamp form among the output for that command, while running `stat foobarfile` shows a date from a few months ago.  So I'm guessing this is the output I'm looking for, but I'd like a 2nd opinion.

By the way, running `which stat` returns `/usr/bin/stat`.  A `grep` in the `/usr/bin` directory for all executables with `stat` in their name returns the following:

- db_stat
- diffstat
- httpdstat.d
- jstat
- jstatd
- lockstat
- lpstat
- nfsstat
- plockstat
- snmpnetstat
- snmpstatus
- stat
- uustat
- vm_stat

As I stated above, my guess is that `stat` returns the output that I had expected `lstat` to return.  My questions are:

- why is `lstat` apparently not installed in my system, when `man lstat` recognizes `lstat` as a valid command?
- Why include manual information for an executable you don't ship with?
- `brew search lstat` returns no results.  Is it possible to install `lstat` to my local machine somehow, and are there even any advantages to doing so?

Comment: try `stat -L` .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Section 1 of the BSD Manual is for general commands.  Section 2 is for system calls, *i.e.*, function calls you might make if programming for your system in the `C` language, or one of its derivatives.

The number in parentheses indicates what section of the manual the entry is from.  In this case, `lstat(2)` indicates that this page provides information on a system call, not on a standalone binary which can be executed at the command-line.

---

If you typed `man lstat`, you would see the manual page for the `lstat` system call.  `stat`, by contrast, is the name of *both* a system call and a standalone utility.  If you type `man stat`, you will by default get the manual page for the command line utility.  To see the system call manual page, you would need to explicitly tell `man` which section of the manual to search:

```
man 2 stat
```

---

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/manpages.5.html is an (outdated) link listing all the sections of the BSD Manual.  The sections will be the same on your system, but I can't find that there is a man page explicitly listing the sections.

Comment: Try `man(1)`, it usually contains a list of sections.

Comment: The manual page pointed to in the answer _is_ a manual page explicitly listing the sections.

Comment: @Kevin, that works on my linux and OpenBSD systems, but I don't think `man(1)` contains the list on recent OSX systems.  I'd be happy to be corrected, but the link I gave was the only OSX man page I could find listing sections, and it is a man page not available on more recent versions of OSX.

Comment: @user4556274 you mentioned System 2 calls are for programming for your system in the C language, or one of its derivatives.  If I want to write a script and use the `lstat` command, how would I go about that?  Will lstat work in a file if I set the file extension to `.c` and compile it?  Or can I use the C-shell shebang (i.e. `#!/bin/csh -f`)?

Comment: `lstat` can be used in a C program with `#include <sys/stat.h>` (listed in man page synopsis). `csh`, while it is named after C, only has a more C-like syntax than other shells. It does not actually compile C code and is not a variant of the C language. If you want to use `lstat` in a script, then you just use the `stat` *command*. The command `stat` uses `lstat` by default, unless you use the `-L` switch, in which case it uses `stat`.